# Почему при landscape UI рисуется правильно а при portrait неправильно?

Tags: android, android-studio, ui, width

Почему при landscape UI рисуется правильно а при portrait неправильно, в то время как оба варианта рисуются автоматически на основе пару строк java кода (одинаковый для обоих режимов)?

Вот скрин превью IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот инфо про превью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, с помощью которого автоматический меняются размеры элементов UI

```
 @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        //размеры выбранной версии превью, на основе которого я собрал нужный UI для программы 
        int testedWidth = 1200;
        int testedHeight = 1920;

        //получаем размер экрана устройства/дисплея
        metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

        widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);
        heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);

        ...

        for (TextView textView : textViews) {
            viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
            viewHeight = textView.getHeight();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = copyLp((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams());
            lp.width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            lp.height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            // Setting the parameters on the TextView
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        ...
```

вот результат с устройства (сделал скрин экрана)

landscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

portrait

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

СУТЬ Проблемы: При правильном результате, во время portrait, width ViewGroup (содержащего элементы в виде луп) должен стать равным width экрана устройства, в смысле - левая сторона ViewGroup должен прикасаться к левой стороне экрана, также как и правая сторона ViewGroup - к правой стороне экрана. Но в результате как видно - присутствуют открытые пространства между ЛСЭУ-ЛСВ и между ПСЭУ-ПСВ, что указывает на то, что width ViewGroup не является равным width устройства.

Уточнение: ЛСЭЮ - это "Левая Сторона Экрана Устройства" а ЛСВ - это "Левая Сторона Вьюгруппы", ПСЭУ-ПСВ соответственно "Правая Сторона Экрана Устройства"-"Правая Сторона Вью".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pokemon_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tvWidthSmallBoard"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tvHeightSmallBoard"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_for_searchboard_cell"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/click_me"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>   
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

растягивается неправильно. По идее должно было растягиваться так, чтобы размер width данного ViewGroup совпало с размером displayWidth (width устройства, на котором запущена программа).

как из выше кода известно

```
int testedWidth = 1200;
int testedHeight = 1920;
```

а размеры экрана, которые программа находит для экрана устройства

width = 1080
height = 2131

Страннее то, что при landscape - проблемы нет, width растягивается как положено, но при portrait почему то, вместо достаточного растягивания, программа решает рисовать маленькими все лупы справа, но почему так происходит, если ViewGroup содержащий лупы - не имеет жестких границ а имеет значение wrap_content?

Я сам не смог найти логического обьяснения для данной ситуации.

Доп. инфо:

Значения размеров в xml переданы не в "dp" а в "px". Зачем именно так? Это связано с уменьшением хлопот во время измерения размеров и делания расчетов. Недавно с "dp" значениями делал программу, количество проблем взбесило, пришлось перейти к "px". Для динамического изменения размеров элементов UI это несомненно правильное решение, поэтому прошу не советовать перейти к "dp".

Вот копи паст dimens.xml (только необходимые строки):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
    <dimen name="tvWidthSmallBoard">400px</dimen>
    <dimen name="tvHeightSmallBoard">200px</dimen>
...
</resources>
```

Хорошо что вспомнил. Забыл указать и этот метод, который используется в программе

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams copyLp(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams source){
        return new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(source);
}
```

Comment: а displayWidth / Height корректно вычисляются?, обычно это делается по другому

Comment: @woesss Спасибо за замечание. Учту. Вопрос обновлен. Если что то сделано не так, дайте знать, исправим остатки недоработок.

Comment: @Style-7 "а displayWidth / Height корректно вычисляются?," Не уверен. Скажу почему. Волнует то, что наличие и отсутствие Action Bar никак не влияет на значение вычисленного displayWidth или displayHeight.  Ну я пробовал и так. Взял и поэксперементировал в режиме portrait отсутствие и наличие Action Bar-а. На удивление - displayHeight как был 2131 таким и остался. Я бы сделал предположение, что это может быть причиной моей проблемы, но суть в том, что в режиме portrait - это не несет ни пользы не вреда, так как мы рассматриваем не height ViewGroup -а а Width.

Comment: Насчет "обычно это делается по другому" я не знаю как по другому это можно сделать. У меня нет опыта работы на коммерческой основе (не фриланс и не офис и не удаленка), поэтому вполне могу допустить смешные ошибки или использовать не оптимальные или давно устаревшие подходы.

Comment: Думаю скоро вам подскажут как это сделать без расчётов вообще - есть более подходящие контейнеры, но я в них слабо ориентируюсь. А вот в расчётах я бы сделал не так: зная, что мне нужно поделить ширину экрана между тремя (да не важно сколько их) элементами, я бы поделил её (реальную) на количество элементов и присвоил эту цифру каждому.

Comment: @Style-7 кажется я нашел более действенный метод. вместо Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();  использовал другой подход. Написал код, который берет значения width и height root layout. :) Но как я и говорил, это не решило основную задачу, несмотря на то, что сейчас уже проблема неправильных данных в случае  наличия или отсутствия Action bar-а больше не побеспокоят.

Comment: @woesss я сделал следующим образом. 1) изначально программе даю данные width и height экрана Preview (ну той версии, которую выбрал для создания статической UI)  2) Потом через программу во время Runtime - определяю размеры той части экрана устройства, на котором должно рисоваться созданный мною UI  3) один раз вычисляю коэфициенты отличия между width preview screen -  width device screen's part "root layout" и аналогичным образом и для height. 4) Все размеры всех элементов внутри root-layout изменяются с помощью этих двух коэфициентов в результате срабатывания метода onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: самый простой способ перевести dp в px и использовать их в разметке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121028/load-dimension-value-from-res-values-dimension-xml-from-source-code

Comment: @Style-7 Но я и так сразу в xml передал px значения вместо dp. Поэтому не понимаю в чем смысл вашего предложения.

Comment: @Style-7 сделал измерение, с помощью getWith для проблемного ViewGroup. Измерил через переопределенного метода onRestart. Оказывается следующее: при portrait width динамически изменненного ViewGroup вместо 1080 выводится значение 972, но при landscape все выходит нормально 2130 вместо 2131 (да 1 px погрешность тут нормально, так как при запросе к системе получается 2131 значение но при запросе получения значение для root layout дается 2130, поэтому на самом деле погрешности нет, все четко) (значения получил через Log.i())

Comment: Это было не предложение. Вообще в Андроид разметку в основном делают по другому, хотя такой вариант тоже иногда используют. Ничего мерить не надо, можно установить пропорции, для разных ориентаций делают разные макеты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается проблема имела очень простое решение. 
Корень ошибки был в том, что программа до перерисовки, пытался уместить все три горизонтальные лупы в рамках 1080 px, в то время как UI был разработан для 1200px и соответственно для теста, я передал по 400 px каждому View. В результате чего программа работала следующим алгоритмом:

1) поместить 3х400 в 1080

2) в случае невозможности уместить - уменьшить размеры каждого третьего View-лупы.

3) во время перерисовки - взять искаженные во время второго пункта размеры.

4) взятые размеры поменять через коэфициент отличия, который предназначен правильной перерисовки UI

Итог: Появлялась проблема, которую я описал выше.

Решение! Поменял 3-ий пункт алгоритма на следующую

3) во время перерисовки вместо взятия искаженных размеров, взять размеры сразу из списка dimens.xml с помощью getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tvWidthSmallBoard).

Теперь неважно, каким первоначально рисуется UI, во время перерисовки все делается как положено!

Comment: Ну естественно и от первых двух шагов алгоритма стоит избавится, так как они уже не имеют смысла, просто способ избавления от них пожалуй будет не менее трудно найти в связи с тем, что размеры root layout берутся через метод onWindowFocusChanged. Это завязывает мне руки.